# Creating flavor specific classes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I have created two Flavors for my Android app with package name `com.test.flavors`

I have created two flavors:

```
1) flavor1
2) flavor2
```

Now I'm trying to create flavor-specific classes for it: I have created the `flavor1` folder under the `src` one, and under that I have created the package folder with name `com.test.flavors`.

So basically it is like this:

```
src--->|
       |----->flavor1 -->java-->com.test.flavors
       |
       |----->main --> All classes and resources as generally present
       |
       |----->flavor2 --> java-->This is where I cannot create the package directory
```

Now when I am trying to achieve the same thing for the `flavor 2` I am not able to achieve it. After creating the `java` folder in `flavor2` folder I am not able to create the package folder with the name `com.test.flavors`. Also the `java` folder in Android Studio viewer is blue for `main` as well as `flavor1` where as for `flavor2` it is not blue in color.

Can any one help me rectify the error?

Comment: Have you switched to the flavour you want to work on?

Comment: have you tried to add folders using android studio menus? you can create directories from inside android studio.

Comment: @Afshin Yes I have tried creating from Android Studio as well as normal way.

Comment: @manfcas Sorry could not understand you statement. Can you please explain "switched to the flavor".

Comment: Once the flavor is created in gradle, you should sync and it should appear in the "Build Variants" panel.

Comment: @manfcas Extremely Thank You that was the only issue. Can You please post an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @manfcas Also will I have to always change the flavor to work on it? How to build the release and debug build of a flavor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to compile files for a specific flavor, you have to:

1. Include it into your `build.gradle` script.
2. Click on `Sync Project with Gradle Files`.
3. Switch to a build variant based on that flavor in the `Build Variants` panel (either ending with `Debug` or `Release`, even it the first one is the common choice while developing).

This is pretty annoying, as you can't compile more than one build variant while you code. If you add a class to a flavor referencing it from the main code and forget to add it to the other flavors in the same flavor dimension, you will break them without seeing any error. You can always build more than one build variant from the `Build` > `Generate Signed APK` wizard though (on a Mac, just press <kbd>cmd</kbd> while you select all the variants you want to build), so some of the APKs may be built and others not.